# How to place MenuBar In App TitleBar? In UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, winui

I make a UWP project in Visual Studio. I have a MenuBar on MainPage.xaml file.
MenuBar code:

```xml
<muxc:MenuBar>
   <muxc:MenuBarItem Title="Item1">
      <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Flyout Item1"/>
   </muxc:MenuBarItem>
</muxc:MenuBar>
```

I want to place MenuBar in Application TitleBar. How do I do that with C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs [Windows Title bar customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/title-bar?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077&tabs=winui2#interactive-content)

You must call `SetTitleBar` to define an area as the draggable title bar region.

Use `ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true` to hide the default title bar and your `MenuBar` will be displayed at the top of the title bar.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="48"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="AppTitleBar" Background="Transparent">
        <!-- Width of the padding columns is set in LayoutMetricsChanged handler. -->
        <!-- Using padding columns instead of Margin ensures that the background
    paints the area under the caption control buttons (for transparent buttons). -->
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="LeftPaddingColumn" Width="0"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="RightPaddingColumn" Width="0"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    </Grid>

    <!-- This control has a higher z-order than AppTitleBar, 
so it receives user input. -->
    <MenuBar HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <MenuBarItem Title="Item1">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Flyout Item1"/>
        </MenuBarItem>
    </MenuBar>

    <AutoSuggestBox QueryIcon="Find"
        PlaceholderText="Search"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Width="260" Height="32"/>
</Grid>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    // Hide default title bar.
    CoreApplicationViewTitleBar coreTitleBar =
        CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
    coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;

    // Set caption buttons background to transparent.
    ApplicationViewTitleBar titleBar =
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
    titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;

    // Set XAML element as a drag region.
    Window.Current.SetTitleBar(AppTitleBar);


}
```

Comment: Hello, It works fine but I have a problem. Can't click to Menu Bar Items. Can you help me? Sorry I'm new.

Comment: I fixed the Menu Bar Items issue.